# Pro and cons of MockPP and Google Mock

Tags: c++, mocking, googlemock

How do the following mocking frameworks compare to each other?  What are their main limitations compared to their Java counterparts?

- [MockPP](http://mockpp.sourceforge.net/)
- [Google Mock](http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/)

Comment: You might also check out [turtle mock](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/turtle/index.php).

Answer (score 1):

I just used google mock, and it works great. The frame work has lots of features (guys really thought of everything).

The only bad thing about it, is that sometimes it is not possible to tell where a call failed, because it just print an uninterested call, but not the line and file where it really happened. Like for example this :

```
GMOCK WARNING:
Uninteresting mock function call - returning directly.
    Function call: UpdateReferences()
```

I can't tell you anything about MockPP and java counterparts, because I never used them. And I can't tell how they compare to google mocks.